# Find the convergence radius for $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2^{n-1}x^{2n-1}}{(4n-3)^2}$

Tags: real-analysis

> Find the convergence radius for $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2^{n-1}x^{2n-1}}{(4n-3)^2}$

I'm trying to understand why this solution is wrong:

We can look at this as a power series with $a_n = \begin{cases}
 & \frac{2^{n-1}}{(4n-3)^2} \text{ if power of } x \text{ is odd} \\ 
 & 0 \text{ if power of } x \text{ is even}
\end{cases}$

And then using Cauchy–Hadamard we would get $R=\frac{1}{2}$.

On the other hand, if we substitute $t=x^2$ we get that the radius is $R=\frac{1}{2}$ **for t**, meaning $R=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ for x. Which is actually the correct solution.

I don't get why the first solution is wrong, explanation will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first method your formula for $a_n$ is not correct. To find $a_n$, the coefficient of $x^{n}$, where $n$ is odd, write $n=2m-1$ or $m=\frac {n+1} 2$. Then you get $a_n=\frac {2^{m-1}} {(4m-3)^{2}}=\frac {2^{(n-1)/2}}{ (2n-1)^{2}}$

Answer (score 4):

You gave the formula for $a_{2n-1}$, not $a_n$. You need $t=x^2$ to convert the series into a form Cauchy-Hadamard addresses.